# Difficulty with a differentiation of measures proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

This shows up in a proof about differentiating measures. I'm having trouble figuring it out:

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\mathcal{C}_r(x)$ denote the set of open cubes with diameter less than $r > 0$ which contain $x$. Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on the Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, assumed to be finite on bounded sets. Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure.

How can I prove that $B = \{x: \sup_{C_r \in \mathcal{C}_r(x)} \frac{\mu(C_r)}{m(C_r)} >a\}$ is open?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this for a couple hours and think I have come up with a solution.
I found it is easier to prove that $B^c$ is closed:

Suppose $\sup_{C_r \in \mathcal{C}_r(x_n)} \frac{\mu(C_r)}{m(C_r)} \leq a$ for $x_n \to x$. Let $C_{k} \in \mathcal{C}_r(x)$ be a sequence of sets such that $\frac{\mu(C_{k})}{m(C_{k})} \to \sup_{C_r \in \mathcal{C}_r(x)} \frac{\mu(C_{r})}{m(C_{r})}$. Because each $C_{k}$ is an open set containing $x$, we can find a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $x_{n_k} \in C_k$ for all $k$. But this implies $C_k \in \mathcal{C}_r(x_{n_k})$, so we have

$$
\frac{\mu(C_k)}{m(C_k)} \leq \sup_{C_r \in \mathcal{C}_r(x_{n_k})} \frac{\mu(C_r)}{m(C_r)} \leq a
$$

Taking limits yields the desired result.